# Laravel - BindingResolutionExceptionUnresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-request, laravel-response

I'm unable to accept post request in Laravel because of following exception

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 819:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request
```

Before occurance of this error I just made routes for authentication,

```
php artisan make:auth
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4, PHP 5.6.25, Apache 2.4.23

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: The command should be <<php artisan make:auth>>

Comment: If your problem still persist. Elaborate your problem! it doesn't make any sense what problem you are facing. It seems like you have drawn your conclusion