# Laravel Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5, guzzle

When posting form I am getting this exception

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request

Searched and tried many ways to solve this but no progress. Seems that my problem is same as [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808138/laravel-bindingresolutionexceptionunresolvable-dependency-resolving-parameter/47518525?noredirect=1#comment81993198_47518525)

Any positive response will be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I had the same error and found solution by removing following line.

`use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;`

and use following Request class instead.

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

I hope it will help you too.

Comment: The dangers of calling a class 'Request'. My IDE offers like 12 Request classes from all kinds of installed packages. Doesn't even help that both `Illuminate\Http\Request` and `Illuminate\Http\Client\Request` exist in Laravel

Answer (score 9):

I have also faced same error like in Laravel

> Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $method ]] in class GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request.

But when I changed

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
```

to

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

then the problem was gone.

Answer (score 8):

I have supplied parameters to _contruct function which do not have default value.

```
protected $method;

public function __construct($method){
}
```

I changed it to

```
protected $method;

public function __construct($method=''){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is already solved, but someone can need an additional help:

In my case problem was in controller.

Make sure that the Request is setted up in correct way **starting from Controller.**

From:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Client\Request;
```

To:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```